# Basic Picasso errors?

Tags: android, picasso

I'm trying to learn how to use Picasso but having some problems with a basic code. I have an imageView and trying to load a url picture into it.

Error ;

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target must not be null.
```

MainActivityCode;

```
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ImageView Imageview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Picasso.with(this).load("http://egyptianstreets.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/egyptischemoefti.jpg").into(Imageview);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to first use `setContentView`, after that initialize the `imageView`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ImageView Imageview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        Picasso.with(this).load("http://egyptianstreets.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/egyptischemoefti.jpg").into(Imageview);
    }
}
```

Your `imageView` cannot be initialized before you had set the `content`, so it is `null` and `Picasso throws` this `exception`.
And by the way, don´t call your `ImageView` **ImageView**, give it another not so confusing name like `mImageView`, `mMyImageView` or somthing else that is not similar to `Android Object` names.